# SSMS 2008 Object Explorer 'Refresh' not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

Using SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio, when I make a change to a database object, then click 'Refresh' in Object Explorer, the items in Object Explorer are not updated. For example, if I right-click a table and select 'Design', then remove a column from the table, when I save my change and click Refresh in Object Explorer, the Columns listed under the table still shows the removed column. Shouldn't 'Refresh' update the Object Explorer content? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your scenario (SQL Server 2008 R2 in SSMS) created and saved a table with two columns. I reopened the table, removed a column and saved the changes. Without refreshing anything when I expanded the column list the removed column was gone. Did you save your changes?

Comment: Hmm, seems to be working now. Not sure what I was doing differently. (I'm a noob at SQL.)  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've been having this problem since SQL 2000.  No amount of refreshing the explorer tree helps.  Sometimes I just have to close SSMS and reopen it before I see my updated objects.  The problem extends to Diagrams as well.  They're out of sync until the object cache is properly updated.